# Breaking down multiple sed commands piped together for error handling

Tags: linux, bash, sed, pipe

I am having some trouble doing error handling when using `sed` in Linux.

I am trying to break down the below line of code

```
#sed -e "s|\${CarbonName}|$BasicName|g" /scripts/templates/artifactfile.xml| sed -e "s|\${Version}|$TotalVersion|g"| sed -e "s|\${SynapseType}|${ArtifactArray[i]}|g"| sed -e "s|\${FileName}|$FullFile|g" > ${CarDir}/${BasicName}_${TotalVersion}/artifact.xml
```

So I took the approach of breaking down the multiple `sed` commands into single ones and using variables to provide it to the next ones, like this:

```
varSedA1="$(sed -e "s|\${CarbonName}|$BasicName|g" /scripts/templates/artifactfile.xml)"
            varSedA2="$($varSedA1 | sed -e "s|\${Version}|$TotalVersion|g")"
            varSedA3="$($varSedA2 | sed -e "s|\${SynapseType}|${ArtifactArray[i]}|g")"
            varSedA4="$($varSedA3 | sed -e "s|\${FileName}|$FullFile|g")"
            echo "$varSedA1, $varSedA2, $varSedA3, $varSedA4"
            if [ -z "$varSedA1" ] ||  [ -z "$varSedA2" ] || [ -z "$varSedA3" ] || [ -z "$varSedA4" ]; then
                echo "error"
                exit 1
            fi
            $varSedA4 >> ${CarDir}/${BasicName}_${TotalVersion}/artifact.xml
```

This way I can check if any of the variables in the process is empty before I write to `artifact.xml`

However, I can't get this to work. I use an `echo` line to show all the variables, but only the first one gets filled.

Comment: Both ways are terrible, just use a single command/script.

Comment: It is indeed a very tedious process, do you perhaps know a better way to fill in xml templates? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Use an xml parser, you're going to have a lot of trouble with anything but trivial replacements using regex. I use  `XML::LibXML` package with perl. `XML::Simple` is also good for quick stuff though.